# How often would you run the Postgresql maintenance tasks

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, database-performance, maintenance

After reading the Postgresql documentation, we found that it's recommendable [to run the Vacuum tasks daily](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-vacuum.html):

> We recommend that active production databases be vacuumed frequently (at least nightly), in order to remove dead rows.

Nonetheless, we're considering running the Reindex tasks in a daily basis too, but we're concerned about the possible implications of doing it (maybe the database size could increase as a consequence of the daily reindex, for example)

#### How often do you run the Vacuum tasks in your DBs?

#### How often do you run the Reindex tasks in your DBs?

#### What do we have to consider when reindexing the DBs (which kind of negative consequences could it brings?)

Answer (score 2):

> How often do you run the Vacuum tasks in your DBs?

All the time (with `autovacuum=on`) and also weekly with `vacuumdb -avz`, logging output to file.

> How often do you run the Reindex tasks in your DBs?

Only when needed. To check if it is needed see -> http://bucardo.org/check_postgres/check_postgres.pl.html#bloat, http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat

> What do we have to consider when reindexing the DBs (which kind of
>   negative consequences could it brings?)

Unneeded I/O, unneeded locking.